# How Do I Fix Laravel 419 Error on Laravel UI Package

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm running into an issue on my local hosted Laravel project that's making it impossible for me to continue working on an important project. I'm getting a 419 Page Expired error when logging into the project. I'm using the default views from the  `laravel/ui` package, from what I can tell through my research is that it's an issue with my CSRF token but the hidden input field on my login form keeps changing and from what I can tell, it's not supposed to do that, I've provided some info that may or may not help but any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I can also confirm that this doesn't seem to happen with other projects I've got on localhost so it's not something to do with my server configuration.

This is the URL of my localhost
[image]

This is the error I get when looking at the network tab on the console.
[image]

My session.php

```
return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

My .env session related variables

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I've tried to use both `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: change `SESSION_LIFETIME` value to be larger and clear config cache then try again

Comment: A URL is not a domain. Fix your `SESSION_DOMAIN` value, or remove it altogether.